# Ajax cant access a file inside directory UP from the app's root folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im using this ajax call:

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#compare_btn').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var id=jQuery('#compare_btn').attr('name');
    alert(id);
    jQuery.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      data:{'propid':id},
      url: "compareAjax.php",
      success:function(result){
        alert(result);
      },
       error: function(req) {
                alert('Error: ' + req.status);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

The **compareAjax.php** contains only a

```
echo "working";
```

When i use for `url : compareAjax.php` and i place the file in the root folder of my site it is working as intended.

But when i move the file to: `components/com_iproperty/views/compare/`
and change url to `"components/com_iproperty/views/compare/compareAjax.php"`
 I get back a 500 Error from ajax request status.

Thinks i did :

- From firebug i checked the Networking tab and the Request URL from
  call is correct.
- I added both my file and folder to www-data group
- Changed the permissions of both of em at 777

None of em worked.
I moved file to components folder and changed the url of ajax also but again a 500 error pops.

Seems to be a server side issue but cant find out what. Does anyone have any idea what is going on ?

Comment: Indeed, this is most likely a server side issue.  Look at your PHP log to see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `url` property as shown below.

```
url: "components/com_iproperty/views/compare/compareAjax.php",
```

Comment: What is the full path of `compareAjax.php` that gets access via url. Try to put that

Answer (score 0):

try to use absolute path, sometimes helped for me:

```
url: "/components/com_iproperty/views/compare/compareAjax.php",
```